# the usage of the punctuation

Tags: punctuation

Alow for the below sentence:

> In the middle of the day, for example, for every person, we, here, have to provide some drinks.

I know that my sentence is a mess. But sometimes I face with sentences that initiate with some prepositions in papers. My sentence is not from paper, but I tried to put forward an example like them. Then my questions are:
1- we can set just one "," after all prepositional phrases, like:

"In the middle of the day for example for every person, we, here, have to provide some drinks."
OR
after each prepositional phrase one "," should be used?

2- The usage of punctuation is respected?
3- It is possible to reduce the number of punctuations without hurting the meaning (in the formal text)?

Comment: The use of commas in your sentence are perfectly understandable. Depending on the exact emphasis you want, they could even be appropriate. However, most people would rephrase the sentence in order to reduce the number of commas. But, grammatically, they actually work. One possible rephrasing that mostly conveys the same meaning and stylistic flow is: *In the middle of the day and for every person, for example, those of us here have to provide some drinks.*

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is a mess.

You need to completely restructure to avoid all the interruptions

> For example, we have to provide some drinks to every person here in the middle of the day.

That is normal and legible and uses one comma.  The word "here" is probably redundant, and "provide everybody with drinks" is probably better.

Answer (score -1):

It would help to have a little more info about the situation you're trying to describe.

It might be that you're saying that the drinks must be provided by us, right here, at a particular time (midday). But more likely you're saying you must provide drinks for every person who is here, and it must occur at midday.

In that case you could clarify the situation by saying,"...every person here..." and eliminate two commas. Then place 'we' after that so you're saying,"For every person here we have to provide drinks" and eliminate another comma.

You can place 'for example,' at the beginning or end of the sentence, and the time (in the middle of the day) after 'for example' or at the very beginning.